# Ubuntu installs on USB external enclosure but doesn't install while it is installed / mounted inside laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

Ubuntu (both 20.04 and 22.04) installs perfectly while in a USB external  enclosure (which is basically USB to SATA for those who don't know), but after it's mounted inside of my laptop it starts giving errors.

Before trying without the enclosure I was getting Errno 30 (Read-only file system error) while trying to install Ubuntu. After multiple tries and a lot of drive checks and a complete drive erase I tried to install it on a enclosure which installed without any errors and booted while still inside of enclosure. After unplugging it and installing it back on laptop it started to give errors.

Laptop specs:

- 4 GB DDR3 RAM
- Intel T6570
- Nvidia 320M
- Model Asus, K50ID

I also tried few other things like:

`nomodeset no=acpi` deleting quiet and splash
Burning ISO with both Rufus and Balena Etcher
Redownloading ISO and checking hash
I tried with both USB 2.0 and USB 3.0

I'm out of ideas at the moment. Also the SSD is brand new. I checked with multiple programs like HDSentinel and it is fine, No SMART errors or bad sectors. BIOS is up to date.

The thing I don't get is, why does it install while in the enclosure without any problems and boot up, but after installing Ubuntu back on laptop (the SSD) it still gives errors. Windows 7 also installs without errors.

SSD installed inside laptop:

[image: SSD installed inside laptop]

Ubuntu installation with enclosure:

[image: Ubuntu installation with enclosure]

Ubuntu installation with enclosure:

[image: Ubuntu Installation with Enclosure]

[image: Log file for failed installation]

Comment: What kind of errors you are asking about? "it started to give Errors." is not informative.

Comment: I/O Error's for example while doing an update.

Thanks!

Comment: RO errors imply to me a problem with the install & I'd not trust it or consider it valuable/reliable from what you said; the actual specific error messages are where I'd look at first as your messages imply a faulty install or hardware issues that should be explored.  We're limited to detail you provide which currently is unclear & reads as you skipping vital clues as to problems (to me anyway; if you don't understand an error; read system logs for clues.. but we can only help if you provide that detail exactly for us to see)

Comment: If this is a UEFI install, see launchpad bug 1396379 (grub installs to wrong place).

Comment: Thank you all, Added log file and screenshots.

Also want to fix I/O error's that i wrote earlier. It is something like Write error along with Interface error

Answer (score 0):

Issue was chipset.Thanks for help!

Edit:
After trying multiple disk's swapping parts (disassembling CD-Rom and putting a SATA Adapter instead of CD-Rom) i thought to myself "at this point it isin't about drives it is about other parts of hardware" so researched something like "Do USB's have their own chipset?"

[Found this answer](https://www.quora.com/Do-things-like-flash-drives-have-a-processor-in-them-if-so-how-powerful-are-they)

What i understand from this is:

My laptop's chipset is partly broken that's why it still can detect drive's and do operations on them.But still gives ATA Error's alongside with "WRITE FPDMA QUEUED" error. But when i connect an enclourse to it, It uses enclourse's chipset and not the one thats in laptop.

Comment: To be an answer needs some details How do you know this and references like a link.